# vscode debugger and running from cmd is not the same?

Tags: python-3.x, cmd, python-import, vscode-debugger

I have a peace of code like this:

```
f = open('a.txt', 'a')
f.write('benis')
f.close()

f = open('a.txt', 'r')
print(f.read())
f.close()
```

When I run it via debugger i keep getting this:

```
run1) benis
run2) benisbenis
...
```

All looks OK?

**But** I have this in a.txt: "sample"

When i run it via cmd:

```
run1) samplebenis
run2) samplebenisbenis
```

**But, I've got more!**

If I run it via cmd it works like intended. Txt updates every time. Updates saves in it.

If I run it via debugger it saves his own "a.txt"... but I don't know where.
Even after PC reboot it still exist somewhere in memory. Idk, there is no new files in this directory, nothing at all

Situation explained. Now, questions

How can I debug normally?
Where VScode keeps it's "a.txt"?

(And maybe someone could say in comments, should i open file to write, then close, then open to read, then close, or I can do it whith only one opening?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running it in Debugger and Command line is not the same. That is because you specify the environment and other variables in the launch.json(and other json files) in the debugger.

So when your running in Debug mode the file is probably created in some other directory(most probably the user directory).

If you want to run the code in debug mode like how it runs in the command-line, then edit the launch.json files in the vscode's debugger to use the directory that you want.

As for reading and writing to a file, unless you will do some other task between reading and writing, you can reuse the same file object. But u need to seek back to the start of the file.

Comment: This might help you for that. [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging#_launchjson-attributes)